# Linq To SQL: Most Efficient Way of Looping through List of ID's

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

Say I have a list of ID's:

```
int[] ids = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

I already have a compiled LINQ statement that returns the individual row (lets call them "Bar" here). So I could just do this:

```
var foo = new List<Bar>();
var len = ids.Length;
for (int i=0; i < len; i++)
{
    foo.Add(db.GetBarByID(ids[i]));
}
```

What I'm wondering is, if there's a more efficient way of doing this? There's not that much data being returned (several `nvarchar` and `int` columns) per row and the list of ID's can be up to 50.

Update:

I'll elaborate on "GetBarByID". It's a simple LINQ statement which returns "Bar".

```
class Bar
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
    public string Blah{get;set;}
}

IQueryable<Bar> GetBarByID(int ID)
{
    return db.Bar
            .Where(w => w.Barid == ID)
            .SelectMany(b => Othertable.Where(w => w.barid == b.id), 
                (b, x) => new Bar { ID = s.id, Name = s.name, Age = s.age, Blah = x.blah });
}
```

Side note: By efficient, i mean clean code and performance wise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's certainly a *simpler* way of writing the same code:

```
var foo = ids.Select(id => db.GetBarById(id))
             .ToList();
```

However, it depends on what `db.GetBarById` really does. If you can use `ids` itself in your query, you might be able to do the whole thing in a single database query:

```
var foo = db.Bars
            .Where(b => ids.Contains(b.Id))
            .ToList();
```

Obviously that's not using your existing LINQ query though - if there's more involved in retrieving a single row, you may need to do a bit more work.

EDIT: Okay, now we've got the single method, it's fairly easy... although you should probably be using a join, to be honest... and I suspect your *real* code has `w.Barid == ID` rather than `w.Barid = ID`.

```
var foo = db.Bar
            .Where(w => ids.Contains(w.Barid))
            .SelectMany(b => Othertable.Where(w => w.barid == b.id), 
                                (b, x) => new Bar { ID = s.id, Name = s.name, 
                                                    Age = s.age, Blah = x.blah })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: @rudeovski just stick in the selectmany after the where in Jons answer

Answer (score 3):

```
var myProducts = from bar in db.Bars
             where ids.Contains(bar.Id)
            select bar;
```